# Generated file Error In Android Studio for Unsupported package android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView, But not find the error comes from where

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, auto-generate

I have Migrated to androidx in previous days. After some days,  Once I have created an activity Login_Activity I have found the error in runtime generated file :

```
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\4_tafheem_new\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\out\com\alquran\tafhimul_quran\databinding\FragmentListBinding.java:4: error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
```

[image]

Here you see that the problems refer to the file : `FragmentListBinding.java`

But I did not find in project files any uses of `import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;` I have failed to find where the error comes from. I have deleted the activity Login_Activity, delete build folder, invalidate caches and restart, But no luck. The problem still arises.

Answer (score 0):

At last I have found the error come from a xml layout file named fragment_list :

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And I have changed it to :

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And the error has gone.

So, I think, Android studio should point out the actual file in case of generated files errors.

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerViewwas migrated to AndroidX as well:

Updatebuild.gradle:

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
```

Change layout file:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```